# How IBM Implement WebSphere Application Server SDK for Sun Solaris OS

Tags: solaris, ibm, websphere, application-server

I deploy the same application in IBM-WAS on different OS ( Windows , AIX and SUN-Solaris ) , SDK errors appeared on SDK for just Solaris OS , I refer some sites and it talk that the SDK on Solaris OS was build based on Sun SDK is it write ? so please I need to now if the IBM build the Solaris SDK from scratch or based on sun SDK ??

More Details :
I Installed the same IBM WAS Application Server on two servers as the following :

1- Server1 -> OS (AIX)

2- Server2 -> OS ( Solaris)

these two server on the same network and have the same configuration .

Then I deploy Java Application ( X ) on both servers , the Application X was run on Server1 ( AIX ) without any problem but when I run the Application on Server 2 ( Solaris OS) I faced SDK issue .

So I need to know what the difference between AIX WAS SDK and Solaris WAS SDK ??

Note : I try windows and it was run without any problem .

Comment: sharing the actual errors (from SystemErr.log or the FFDC logs) you encounter might yield answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Websphere, all OS-es, with the EXCEPTION of Solaris, uses IBM's own JDK.  In Solaris, it uses the Sun JDK.  That, unfortunately, is the way it is; it cannot be changed.

As far as I know, it's done that way because of some sort of license restriction/agreement.

You wouldn't see the same problem in Windows because it uses the IBM JDK.

Is there a reason why the application will need to be deployed on WAS on different OSes?  It would appear that the only solution is to correct the code so that the sun JDK issues don't occur.